# How to insert a literal tab instead of auto-completing in Jupyter?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

It is easy to indent a whole line.

1. Just highlight the whole line and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. Go to the start of the line and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Click anywhere in the line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Now the **problem** is how to insert indent in the middle of the line.

And also, how to indent at the end of the line.

Example usage scenario:

```
# Hyperparameters
LENGTH = 10 # length of foo
TEMP = 20 # temperature of bar
IV = 99.99 # induction variability of foo bar
```

Concretely, we want:

```
# Hyperparameters
LENGTH = 10    # length of foo
TEMP = 20      # temperature of bar
IV = 99.99     # induction variability of foo bar
```

Or even better (in some cases):

```
# Hyperparameters
LENGTH = 10        # length of foo
TEMP   = 20        # temperature of bar
IV     = 99.99     # induction variability of foo bar
```

1. Note that by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button however, we are actually calling auto-complete instead of indenting.
2. Of course we can always manual align them by using spacebar, but then we will have to do this every time we tune the hyperparameters.

So, how to indent instead of auto-completing in Jupyter?

P.S. Yes, I am aware of print("\t"), copying the output and pasting the indent. But that is not desirable.

Comment: related github issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10994

Comment: I am looking for a solution of the same problem but I prefer indenting using spaces instead of tabs. I have asked a question in the JupyterLab forum: [How to indent inline comments (end of line comments)?](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-indent-inline-comments-end-of-line-comments/14473?u=vbrozik)

Answer (score 2):

One alternative would be to use the Alt keyboard sequence.
In this case it would be `Alt + 09`. It is about as short as one could hope for.

For this to work you need a numpad on your keyboard, as the top row of numbers on the keyboard does not work to produce Alt keyboard sequences.

However, this does leave rather ugly arrows in place of the tab, which seems to be the way Jupyter Notebooks displays tab characters.

Comment: Unfortunately this inserts the real tab character instead of the standard indentation using spaces.