# How to insert Tab character instead of auto-completing in jupyter notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, codemirror

When pressing `Tab`, I want to insert an Tab character not only in the head of line but also the body, instead of code completion.

Is there any way to solve the problem? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[How to insert a literal tab instead of auto-completing in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497106/how-to-insert-a-literal-tab-instead-of-auto-completing-in-jupyter)

in jupyter `tab` not used as `space`, you can see some solutions in the issue topic

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have known how to insert Tab character by self-define keyboard shortcut(eg. Ctrl-B for inserting tab character). However, `Tab` key still do autocompletion when cursor is not in the head of line. Was I miss something in that issue? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Simply put the tab in a notepad; then copy and paste it into jupyter.